# pthread mutex two threads interchangebly locks/unlocks is it valid approach?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I read that the mutex should be unlocked by same thread that has locked it. Let us consider the following Scenario.

I have a mutex variable say `myMute`, `T1`, `T2` are two threads.

1. `T1` locks the `myMute`.
2. `T2` unlocks `myMute`.
3. `T2` locks `myMute`.
4. `T1` unlocks `myMute`.

Is this ordered locking/unlocking from different threads a valid approach?

Comment: No, that defeats the entire purpose of having a Mutex which is to protect a section of code from being interrupted by another section of code. As you read it should only be unlocked by the code that locked it. It sounds like you have a different problem - maybe you should post the actual problem and ask for the correct solution?

Comment: "Should" is an understatement. A mutex can only be unlocked by the thread that currently holds it. Any attempt to unlock it by another thread results in potentially-very-dangerous undefined behavior.

Comment: "A valid approach" to what?  What is it you're really trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

No, this is incorrect. From `pthread_mutex_lock` man page:

> If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.

Example correct ordering:

- T1 locks myMutex
- T2 locks myMutex (blocked waiting for T1 to unlock the mutex)
- T1 unlocks myMutex (T2 now locks mutex)
- T2 unlocks myMutex

EDIT:

Small example using `pthread_cond_wait()` with error checking omitted for brevity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

volatile int value = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mymutex;
pthread_t thread_one;
pthread_t thread_two;
pthread_cond_t cond;

void* main_one(void* ignored)
{
    while (value < 10)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mymutex);
        fprintf(stderr, "T1: value=%d\n", value);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);
    }
    return (void*)0;
}

void* main_two(void* ignored)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mymutex);
        value++;
        fprintf(stderr, "T2: value=%d\n", value);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
        fprintf(stderr, "Broadcasted but T1 cannot continue for 1 second\n");
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mymutex);
        pthread_yield();
    }

    return (void*)0;
}

void start_thread(void* (*a_entry_point)(void*),
                  pthread_t* a_handle)
{
    pthread_attr_t thread_attributes;

    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attributes);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attributes, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(a_handle, &thread_attributes, a_entry_point, 0);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_t thread_one_handle;
    pthread_t thread_two_handle;

    /* Init mutex. */
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mymutex, &attr);

    /* Init condition. */
    pthread_cond_init(&cond, 0);

    /* Start threads. */
    start_thread(main_one, &thread_one_handle);
    start_thread(main_two, &thread_two_handle);

    /* Wait for threads. */
    pthread_join(thread_one_handle, 0);
    pthread_join(thread_two_handle, 0);

    /* Clean up. */
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mymutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -Wall -Werror -D_GNU_SOURCE main.c -o main -pthread`.

Comment: 1) Well, let me take  pthread_cond_wait as a example. it unlocks the associated mutex, and waits, once received signal, then locks.  2). The mutex can be used to set the flag, and to signal condition variable.  3). I read Advanced linux programming by Mark,Jeffrey, and alex, wherein 4.4 synchronisation and critical session chapter, the same code is provided. the same mutex variable is used to set the condition flag, and the same mutex is associated with wait on condition variable.  I hope i delivered  my question properly. :)

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` must be called with the mutex locked, or, as before, undefined behaviour results.

Comment: Yes, true, but what i point out is pthread_cond_wait automatically unlocks the mutex, and then locks once wait is over. In between the object waiting to change the flag can use this same mutex right ?, that is scenario i mentioned in the question. :).

Comment: Some other thread can use that mutex, in which case the `pthread_cond_wait` would be unable to return. See [Condition Variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) for a description of this.

Comment: The whole point is that `pthread_cond_wait` does not return until it can obtain the mutex again.